# How to install a TFS extension only on some project instead the whole collection

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

we have a TFS collection with a huge amount of projects inside (it's a design choice).

We have create extensions (that works great), but out current problem is: **How to install the extension not on the whole collection.**

If the solution is to install it on the whole collection but hide it after with a setting, it should be great too.

I have take a look inside the manifest, but for now I hadn't found the solution.
Has anyone have a clue about this problematic ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is **not supported** for now. When you install an extension, you need to specify a collection, **the extension will be installed for all team projects under this collection.**

But for a paid extension, you can restrict who can access it by [Assigning paid extension access to users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/marketplace/assign-paid-extensions?view=vsts)

There have been **user voices** below to suggest the feature, you can go and vote it up to achieve that in future release.

- [Limit the custom extensions to specific projects only](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/16469686-limit-the-custom-extensions-to-specific-projects-o)
- [VSTS extension project restrict](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/19331524-vsts-extension-project-restrict)

---

Besides, if you don't want to apply the extension to some team projects under a collection, then as a workaround you can [split a team project collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/split-team-project-collection?view=tfs-2015) to organize your projects into separate collections (`Collection A : The projects which you want to apply the extension; Collection B: The projects which you don't want to apply the extension.`).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll vote it up and take a look with the user access.