# How to show a custom web page in 1 Azure DevOps project only

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I understand I can build Extension, but it appears it will install on all projects in the collection. My custom web page is only relevant to 1 project.

I found this SO question [How to install a TFS extension only on some project instead the whole collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49779871/how-to-install-a-tfs-extension-only-on-some-project-instead-the-whole-collection) but the 3 links in the answer aren't working.

Anyone have any work around suggestion?

Comment: What's with the downvote?The question is clear enough with what I want to achieve and I showed I have tried to looked for the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is shown in the ticket, the extension installed in the `Collection Scope`, the extension will be installed for all team projects.

Azure Devops doesn't support installing extensions for a single project now.

Since you are using the custom web page(**custom extension**), I am afraid that there is **no** method could limit the extension to users.

For some extensions and paid extension, you can restrict users from using this extension by assigning extension to user or changing access level.

You could refer to this doc about [users access extension features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/marketplace/faq-extensions?view=azure-devops-2019#q-why-cant-users-access-extension-features).

Here are the User Voices about this feature, many customers have the same requirement.

[Allow Extensions to be Installed only in Projects](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/407517/allow-extensions-to-be-installed-only-in-projects.html)

[Extensions scoped at a project level](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/537563/extensions-scoped-at-a-project-level.html)

You could vote it and add your thoughts in comment.